# Hibernate: "Instantiating explicit connection provider" is extremely slow

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am using **Hibernate** within a **Spring** application to connect to a remote database-server. Is there any chance to speed up the Connection provider instantiation process by configuration?

```
Instantiating explicit connection provider: org.hibernate.ejb.connection.InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider>
//takes about 30 seconds
```

Comment: Well probably not. You are injecting a datasource, at startup hibernate creates a connection to validate the entities. Depending on your network and used datasource this might be a slow process. However this is a one time hit if you have configured things right.

Comment: @M.Deinum ... but it can be ennoying in a testing environment, where you start and stop the application very often ... :-(

Answer (score 0):

Let your application server to manage the database connections, don't try to do it in Hibernate. This will create the connections at the server startup and keep it in cache, so it will be just one time delay for you, that too at the server startup.

Comment: I am in a testing environment. The application is not deployed to application server.

Answer (score 0):

For testing environments you should use an in-memory database like HSQLDB or H2. Creating and dropping such database is lightning fast so it will speed-up your testing considerably.

For system integration tests, you might want to connect to a production-like database server, but that clone database server should be collocated to the testing environment to avoid unnecessary networking delays or slow connections.